# Magento Refund Table

Tags: magento

Where can I find the refund tables in Magento?

I want to find out if a person has received refund for a certain product or not?

If no refund tables how magento track that?

Comment: I don't have much experience in Magento. That's why I am writing this answer in a comment. Check all the tables like sales_flat_creditmemo, sales_flat_creditmemo_item etc.

Comment: I found salesrefunded_aggregated and sales_refunded_aggregated_order  but what is the difference between them and sales_flat_creditmemo etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refunding an Order in Magento does not cause an actual payment refund. You must refund the payment on your own. Credit Memo is only a record used to track the refunds and to provide proper values in the reports. Check the below link so that you can get more info about the table relations.

http://www.magento-exchange.com/magento-database/magento-1-4-database-er-diagram-for-sales-credit-memo-tables/

Comment: the link is dead